# Azure-Pipeline: commit hash in Branch\Tag field (in UI) as a variable

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get if user insert a commit hash in Branch\Tag field as a variable in the pipeline itself,
Is there is any way to get this done?

[image]

I mean,

if user have set commit hash, get: `$(commit) = COMMIT-HASH`

If not: `$(commit) = none`

Comment: Can you rephrase your question or provide a pseudocode sample of what you are trying to do? I don't fully understand your question as is.

Comment: It might be that you're looking for `$(Build.SourceVersion)` and no value set for `$(Build.SourceBranch)`

Comment: I mean, if user have set commit hash, get:
$(commit) = COMMIT-HASH
If not:
$(commit) = none

Comment: with $(Build.SourceBranch) I get the branch name that I Build. With $(Build.SourceVersion) I get the commit that I build. I need to get $(Build.SourceVersion) ONLY if I set the commit manualy at "Branch\Tag" feald

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you need to pass the value: **$(Build.SourceVersion)** to custom variable: commit when user manually select the Commit Hash before running Pipeline.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can determine whether the user has chosen commit to run the pipeline.

When we select only branch, it uses Branch + the latest commit, and when we select commit, it uses Branch + the selected commit. When Pipeline processes commit information, it cannot directly judge if the commit is selected by user.

There are no built-in variables to help us check if the commit is selected by user.

For a workaround, you can use script to determine if the commit is latest(latest commit means that user may select the Branch Option without commit) Rest API: [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#on-a-branch) and check if the branch contains **"refs/tags"**(If the branch contains refs/tags, it means that user is selecting tags)

Then you can set the variable in the script.

Here is an example:

PowerShell script: You can add the PowerShell task in the Pipeline to do the actions.

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $token = "$(system.accesstoken)"
   $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
   
   $searchCriteria = "$" + "top=1"
   
   echo $searchCriteria
   
   $Url = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits?searchCriteria.$searchCriteria&api-version=6.0" 
   
   echo $Url
   
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url  -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
   
   echo $response
   
   $latestcommit = $response.value.commitId
   
   echo $latestcommit
   
   $IFSelectTag = "$(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH)".Contains("refs/tags")
   
   echo $IFSelectTag 
   
   if( "$latestcommit" -ne "$(Build.SourceVersion)" -And  "$IFSelectTag"  -eq  "False" )
   {
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commit]$(Build.SourceVersion)"
   
   }
   
   else
   {
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commit]" ""
   }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

**Limitation:** The above script **NOT** able to make a correct judgment when the user manually selects the latest commit of the branch.

Another method is that you can set Pipeline Variable or Pipeline Parameters, when the user trigger the pipeline via commit, you can let them to manually fill in the Variables/Parameters value. Then the pipeline can set the commit variable based on the variables/parameters value.

On the other hand, I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

**Update:**

When you use Pipeline Variable, you need to enable the Option: **Settable at queue time**.

[image]

Then you can see the variable when running the pipeline.

[image]

When you use Pipeline Parameters, you can use the following Yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
- name: IsSelectedCommit  
  type: string
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin!!
I've set the second option, The problame was, It didn't reflected in the UI like if you set it in the "Brunch\Tag" field.
So they need to put it at the bouth places.

Comment: @Mor.sound  I have shared more details about the second option in the answer. You can refer to it. When you run the Pipeline, you will see the variables/parameters in the UI. Since this function is provided as a workaround, it should have limitation and may not fully implement your needs.

Comment: @Mor.sound Is there any update about this ticket? If the answer can give you some help, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, But it's not what I looking for...
It was just like my walk around...
But TNX alot for your help :)))

Comment: @Mor.sound Yes these methods are workarounds. Since there is no method can achieve this feature for the time being, you can create a suggestion ticket to report the feature. The link is in the answer above.

Comment: I have allready did :)

Comment: @Mor.sound you can share the suggestion ticket link here. I will help upvote the ticket to show the support. And you can keep using the workarounds for the time being.